# Failed to failed to configure the microstrategy cloud platform to azure (Code : PrincipalNotFound)

Tags: azure, cloud, microstrategy

I will connect the microstrategy cloud with azure. I have followed the tutorial attached by microstrategy. but when i follow the steps in azure, the system asks for principal id. How can I find the principal ID?

Is the principal id the same as the subscriptions id?

when I use a subscription ID, an error message appears when developing a resource group.

message error : Principal xxxxxxxxx does not exist in the directory (Code : PrincipalNotFound)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HoWqF.png)

Answer (score 1):

Service Principals can be found in the App Registrations section in your Azure Active Directory.

Type **Active Directory** in the top **search box**, select **Azure Active Directory** then **App Registrations** in the left menu.

Comment: There is no application in azure active directory. I followed the steps of this page. 

https://www2.microstrategy.com/producthelp/Current/Cloud/en-us/Content/azure_configuration.htm


I get into trouble in step 8. In tutorial not show input principal ID but when I try Principal ID is required. how can it be different? Is the cause subscription ID free trial license?